# Converting DSD-Audio (.dsf, .dff) to Flac

Tags: flac, foobar2000

so I have got a couple of SACD rips from my Windows-PC as .dsf files on my Hard-Drive. Now I would like to eventually encode those in opus , to play them on my phone. To be able to do that, I need to first convert them into some lossless audio codec [via PCM?!], preferably flac. Unfortunately the only device available to me now runs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

So far I tried foobar2000 via Wine, which couldn't even play them.

Unfortunately i was not able to compile dsf2flac either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use already compiled binary of dsf2flac from [here](https://code.google.com/p/dsf2flac/downloads/detail?name=dsf2flac%20Linux%20x86_64%20revision%2051.zip&can=2&q=).
Unzip it and you will find `dsf2flac` CLI app there. The command should look like:

```
./dsf2flac -i file.dsf -o output.flac
```

type `./dsf2flac -h` to see more options.

You could also try out `ffmpeg`. If you don't want to build and configure it on your own you can download the latest [static builds](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and just start to use it. Also take a look at [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio) site if you decide to use `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I get `dsf2flac: loadlocale.c:129: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion 'cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.`.

Comment: I get the same error.  ```dsf2flac: loadlocale.c:129: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)```

Comment: @JamesIsIn [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444102/loadlocale-c-nl-intern-locale-data-assertion-error) might help you out with that assertion problem. However I would fist try to do it using ffmpeg. It may be faster.

Comment: Yeah, I did use ffmpeg.  Any idea why your version won't work?  Is it the bitrate?  http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2020/02/a-couple-recent-conversions-for-audio-and-video/

Comment: @JamesIsIn It doesn't look like a bitrate. From the assertion you posted it looks like a problem of your locale settings. Also that compiled binary seems to be in debug mode. (usually assertions happen in debug builds.) One could try to compile the newest code itself in release build. But it is not my source code, therefore I don't know if there are further problems etc.

Comment: [shrugs]  I'm not sure I care so much.  I can use ffmpeg to do just about anything anyway.  Maybe I'll hit you up when I get around to posting my inquiry about splitting hi-def flac files.  See you around.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [DeaDBeeF](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net)?

For Ubuntu, download either the i686 (for 32 bit hosts) or amd64 (for 64 bit computers) DEB files: http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/download.html

Once downloaded, say to `~/Downloads`, open Terminal and:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/deadbeef-static_0.7.2-2_amd64.deb
```

You can then run DeaDBeeF.

Add your DSD files using the *Add files* or *Add folders* options on the File menu. This will import your files into the DeaDBeeF list.

Right click the files you want to convert and click... *Convert*:

[image: Converting DSD files with DeaDBeeF]

In the next dialog, set where you want the files saved, and choose the FLAC encoder:

[image]

Click *OK* and the FLAC files will be generated.

---

I wrote up a load of these (because I was always asking myself same questions for different file formats on Linux) at https://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2017/06/20/matrix-free-audio-file-converters/

Comment: I get: `Write error (4096 bytes written out of 16000)
Failed to execute the encoder, command used:
flac -o "/mnt/data/home/aprokope/Music/Dire Straits - A1.Calling Elvis.flac" -5 --ignore-chunk-sizes -`

Comment: Are your FLACs valid? Take a look at https://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2015/03/31/test-flacs-corruption/

Comment: I am going from dff source files to flac output files, and this fails when I press OK in the dialog above. I think that the dff files are valid, since deadbeef plays them correctly.
Also, the dff files are 32-bit and with 192 kHz sampling rate (~500mb each) - maybe the FLAC encoder can't handle this..

Answer (score 1):

Real easy with `ffmpeg`:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i "<nameOfTrack>.dff" -c:a flac "<nameOfTrack>.flac"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked for me. Stream #0:0: Audio: dsd_lsbf_planar, 1411200 Hz, stereo, fltp, 22579 kb/s, 1411200 Hz not supported